# Construction of outer measure where the closed unit interval is not measurable and outer measure there is not equal to set function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, outer-measure

Occasioned by some exercises I saw about creating outer measures in which [0,1] is not measurable because of the definition of the set function that generates the outer measure, I was wondering if given an σ-cover constisting of the closed intervals [a,b] in $\mathbb{R}$ we could create an outer measure m* with a proper function ρ such that
m*([0,1]) $\neq$ ρ([0,1]) AND [0,1] is not m*-measurable

I couldn’t find something online and the main thing that’s been bothering me is that because [0,1] is a closed interval it can be written as a cover of itself and therefore something like that would be true m*([0,1]) $\leq$ ρ([0,1]). How can I define ρ to get rid of the equality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider $(\Bbb R, \Sigma , \mu)$ where $\Sigma$  is the $\sigma$-algebra of countable / co-countable subsets of $ \Bbb R and $\mu(E) = 0 if $E$ is countable and $\mu(E) = 1$ is $E$ is co-countable in $\Bbb R$.

It follows immediately that $[0,1] \notin \Sigma$. Moreover: 
$$ \mu^*(\Bbb R) 1 < 1 +1 = \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]) +  \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]^C)$$
So $[0,1]$ is not measurable (in Caratheodory sense). That is $[0,1]$ is not $\mu^*$- measurable.

Comment: @Ramiro thanks for the reply! From what I understand your set function is $\mu$ and m*($\mathbb{R}$) is one because it’s cocountable and m*([0,1])=1(because of its lebesgue outer measure?) but I can’t understand why m*( $\mathbb{R} $ \ [0,1]) is 1. It doesn’t belong to Σ right? And also it’s lebesgue oute measure is infinity, right?

Comment: Please, see the answer I posted below. In the remarks, I added the details you asked for.

Comment: @Ramiro I see. What if the ρ:C->[0,$\infty$],( where C is a σ-cover of closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ ) that created the outer measure m* wasn’t a measure but a premeasure or something other than measure, could we compare the two quantities then and find them different from each other?

Comment: If $\rho$ is a a pre-measure, the situation remains the same. If $A \notin C$, then $\rho(A)$ is not defined. If $A \in C$, then $\rho(A) = \mu^*(A)$.

Comment: @Ramiro, then what’s the point of an exercise asking us to show that  $\mu^*([0,1]) \neq ρ([0,1])$. Is the exercise wrong for asking that ?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the exercise? What is exactly $\rho$ in the exercise?

Comment: @Ramiro this is the exercise I had in mind when I asked the question Let σ -cover C := {[a, b] : a < b, a, b ∈ R} ∪$0$ of $\mathbb{R}$.Create an outer measure

 μ ∗ : P (R) → [0, +∞], following the general construction of outer measures (starting with a suitable 
τ : C → [0, +∞]), such that 

μ∗([0,1]) $\neq$ τ([0,1]) AND
 [0,1] is not μ∗-measurable.

Comment: What is $0$ as a set in the $\sigma$-cover?  What do you by a suitable $\tau$?  What are the properties of $\tau$?

Comment: @Ramiro judging from what we’ve done already in class τ is just a mapping from the set of σ-covers C to the positive numbers(a promeasure perhaps) with τ(of empty set)=0 as defined in the caratheodory extension theorem and it’s the one whose sum we use to define the outer measure m*. Now, as to why zero is a set in the σ-cover I have no idea

Comment: If the function $\rho$ is not $\sigma$-additive, we can have $\mu^*([0,1]) \neq \rho([0,1])$. See the example 2, that I added to my answer.

Comment: @Ramiro thanks so much for all this feedback. I was kinda confused with this exercise as ρ is a bit ambiguous from the way the exercise defines it. I see it now though, basically for a condition like the one I asked we need to have that ρ is just a function(not a measure, not a promeasure and doesn’t have σ-additivity)

Comment: Ok. You are welcome. If you are satisfied, it would be kind of you to accept my answer (and upvote it, if you have not yet upvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1**: Consider $(\Bbb R, \Sigma , \mu)$ where $\Sigma$  is the $\sigma$-algebra of countable / co-countable subsets of $ \Bbb R$ and $\mu(E) = 0$ if $E$ is countable and $\mu(E) = 1$ is $E$ is co-countable in $\Bbb R$.

It follows immediately that $[0,1] \notin \Sigma$ (because $[0,1]$ is not countable nor co-countable). Moreover:
$$ \mu^*(\Bbb R) =1 < 1 +1 = \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]) +  \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]^C)$$
So $[0,1]$ is not measurable (in Caratheodory sense). That is $[0,1]$ is not $\mu^*$- measurable.

**Remarks**:

1. Please, note that $\mu$ is **not** the Lebesgue measure and $\mu^*$ is **not** the Lebesgue outer measure.
2. Since $\Bbb R$ is co-countable, $\mu^*(\Bbb R)= \mu(\Bbb R) =1$.
3. Since $[0,1] \subseteq \Bbb R$, we have that $\mu^*([0,1])\leqslant \mu^*(\Bbb R)=1 $. On the other hand, since any countable cover of $[0,1]$ by sets in $\Sigma$ must contain at least one co-countable set, we have $\mu^*([0,1]) \geqslant 1$. So  $\mu^*([0,1]) = 1$.
4. By a similar argument, we have that  $\mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]^C)=1$.

**Example 2**: Consider $\Bbb R$ and let $C$ be the semi-algebra of all intervals (including single point intervals and the empty interval).  Let $\rho: C \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ be a function defined defined:
$\rho(I) = 0.1$,  if $I \subsetneq [0,1]$ and $\rho(I)=1$ if $I=[0,1]$ or $I \not \subset [0,1]$.

Note that $\rho$ is not a pre-measure, it is not $\sigma$-additive and it is not even finitely additive.

Let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\rho$. It easy to see that:
$\mu^*([0,1]) = 0.2 < 1 =\rho([0,1])$. I is also easy to see that
$\mu^*(\Bbb R) = 1$  and $\mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]^C) = 1$. It follows
that
$$\mu^*(\Bbb R) = 1 < 1.2 = 0.2 + 1 = \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]) +  \mu^*(\Bbb R \cap [0,1]^C)$$
So $[0,1]$ is not $\mu^*$-measurable.

Note that since $\rho$ is not $\sigma$-additive, $\mu^*$ is not an extension of $\rho$, which we can clearly see from the fact that $\mu^*([0,1]) = 0.2 \neq 1 =\rho([0,1])$.

Comment: sorry for being so thorough but I’m new to measure theory and haven’t developed yet a strong intuition so I have one more question: What gives us  μ*[0,1]$\neq$ μ[0,1], is it the fact that the unit interval does not belong in our algebra ?

Comment: @NoetherBoy For  this measure space $(\Bbb R, \Sigma , \mu)$,  we have that  $[0,1] \notin \Sigma $ and $\mu([0,1])$ is not even defined.

Comment: yeah that was my thought as well, thanks. Do you happen to know if there's an example where μ*[0,1]≠μ[0,1] is true, both of these measures exist and μ is the set function of the outer measure  μ* ?

Comment: @NoetherBoy Such example does not exist. Given any measure space $(X, \Sigma , \mu)$, $\mu$ is defined on $\Sigma$ and for any $A\in \Sigma$, (since $\mu^*$ is the outer measure induced by $\mu$) we have $\mu^*(A)=\mu(A)$.

Comment: I see, so the worst we could have is that μ(Α) $\leq$ μ*(Α), because of the infimum definition. And it’s true no matter what measure we choose for the sum of the measure of the covers of whose infimum is an outer measure?

Comment: @NoetherBoy Given any measure space $(X, \Sigma , \mu)$, $\mu$ is defined on $\Sigma$ and for any $A\in \Sigma$, (since $\mu^*$ is the outer measure induced by $\mu$) we have $\mu^*(A)=\mu(A)$.  What happens is that $\mu^*$ is defined to ALL subsets of $X$, including those that are NOT in $\Sigma$. If a set $A$ is not in $\Sigma$, we don't have $\mu(A)$ (it is not defined). So we can not compare $\mu(A)$ to $\mu^*(A)$.